# element.innerHTML = 'test' not setting inner html, in node with node-html-parser

Tags: node.js, node-html-parser

Can not do a replace operation, or set innerHTML or innerText on dom nodes in node with  node-html-parser.

```
    var HTMLParser = require('node-html-parser');

    var content = `<h1>H1 Tag</h1> <img class="responsive-img img-wrap-right" src="/uploads/small_overwhelmed_debt_85b1046163.png?7215450.285000001" /><p> P Tag Contents</p>`
    var html = HTMLParser.parse(content)

    var domNodes = html.querySelectorAll('*')

    for (const element of domNodes) {

      if (element.outerHTML.includes('<p')) {

        element.innerHTML = 'test'
        console.log('element.innerHTML',element.innerHTML)

      }
    }
```

Output
**element.innerHTML  P Tag Test**

Any idea why I can not set innerHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works just fine.
Make sure you have an appropriate node/npm installed.
I have

```
node -v; npm -v
v18.16.0
9.5.1
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "parser",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-html-parser": "^6.1.5"
  }
}
```

You could also try https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom
It's more popular/powerful.

BTW, don' use `var` for god's sake...

[image]

Comment: You think node 16 is the issue? I will test it and follow up.
Why no Var?

Comment: Updating node did not solve it but updating my node-html-parser version did.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GreggoryWiley `var` creates a lot of subtle bugs, i find using it dangerous nowadays

Comment: @GreggoryWiley try `jsdom` package? seems more matured

Comment: @GreggoryWiley glad you found the reason. yes i used the latest version so it works ok for me

Comment: I usually use Var for variables that I want to be available in child functions without passing them, and let for variables that only scope to the individual function. Is this the wrong idea?
Greggory Wiley

Comment: @GreggoryWiley const and let are also available in child function but they are a lot safer to use. read about the difference between var and const/let https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/